# Git error "non-monotonic index"

Tags: git, git-extensions

My `git` setup has a central repository to which I push. Today I decided to look at the central repository using `Git Extensions`, and it said that the repo has no commits (almost as if the repo was never created). Investigating this issue, I tried to clone the repo, and it gave me some weird errors I've never seen:

```
error: non-monotonic index C:/Temp/N1/Netduino/.git/objects/pack/pack-29a18084cf61cd0322a6e9cfd485ce0977348c53.idx
error: non-monotonic index C:/Temp/N1/Netduino/.git/objects/pack/pack-29a18084cf61cd0322a6e9cfd485ce0977348c53.idx
error: non-monotonic index C:/Temp/N1/Netduino/.git/objects/pack/pack-29a18084cf61cd0322a6e9cfd485ce0977348c53.idx
error: non-monotonic index C:/Temp/N1/Netduino/.git/objects/pack/pack-29a18084cf61cd0322a6e9cfd485ce0977348c53.idx
error: non-monotonic index C:/Temp/N1/Netduino/.git/objects/pack/pack-29a18084cf61cd0322a6e9cfd485ce0977348c53.idx
error: non-monotonic index C:/Temp/N1/Netduino/.git/objects/pack/pack-29a18084cf61cd0322a6e9cfd485ce0977348c53.idx
error: non-monotonic index C:/Temp/N1/Netduino/.git/objects/pack/pack-29a18084cf61cd0322a6e9cfd485ce0977348c53.idx
error: non-monotonic index C:/Temp/N1/Netduino/.git/objects/pack/pack-29a18084cf61cd0322a6e9cfd485ce0977348c53.idx
error: non-monotonic index C:/Temp/N1/Netduino/.git/objects/pack/pack-29a18084cf61cd0322a6e9cfd485ce0977348c53.idx
error: non-monotonic index C:/Temp/N1/Netduino/.git/objects/pack/pack-29a18084cf61cd0322a6e9cfd485ce0977348c53.idx
error: non-monotonic index C:/Temp/N1/Netduino/.git/objects/pack/pack-29a18084cf61cd0322a6e9cfd485ce0977348c53.idx
error: non-monotonic index C:/Temp/N1/Netduino/.git/objects/pack/pack-29a18084cf61cd0322a6e9cfd485ce0977348c53.idx
error: non-monotonic index C:/Temp/N1/Netduino/.git/objects/pack/pack-29a18084cf61cd0322a6e9cfd485ce0977348c53.idx
error: non-monotonic index C:/Temp/N1/Netduino/.git/objects/pack/pack-29a18084cf61cd0322a6e9cfd485ce0977348c53.idx
error: non-monotonic index C:/Temp/N1/Netduino/.git/objects/pack/pack-29a18084cf61cd0322a6e9cfd485ce0977348c53.idx
error: non-monotonic index C:/Temp/N1/Netduino/.git/objects/pack/pack-29a18084cf61cd0322a6e9cfd485ce0977348c53.idx
error: non-monotonic index C:/Temp/N1/Netduino/.git/objects/pack/pack-29a18084cf61cd0322a6e9cfd485ce0977348c53.idx
error: non-monotonic index C:/Temp/N1/Netduino/.git/objects/pack/pack-29a18084cf61cd0322a6e9cfd485ce0977348c53.idx
error: non-monotonic index C:/Temp/N1/Netduino/.git/objects/pack/pack-29a18084cf61cd0322a6e9cfd485ce0977348c53.idx
error: non-monotonic index C:/Temp/N1/Netduino/.git/objects/pack/pack-29a18084cf61cd0322a6e9cfd485ce0977348c53.idx
error: non-monotonic index .git/objects/pack/pack-29a18084cf61cd0322a6e9cfd485ce0977348c53.idx
error: non-monotonic index C:/Temp/N1/Netduino/.git/objects/pack/pack-29a18084cf61cd0322a6e9cfd485ce0977348c53.idx
fatal: unable to read tree cc90183a1571664f80712c0376f59afeb681303f
```

I have searched Google about this issue, and there's also another question on StackOverlow regarding this issue but it remains unanswered ([this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10707690/git-non-monotonic-index)). Anyone able to shed light on this issue? Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(not a complete answer, but at least some clues, and a workaround)

That error message comes from the [`sha1_file.c`, method `check_packed_git_idx()`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/sha1_file.c#L478),

```
nr = 0;
index = idx_map;
if (version > 1)
  index += 2; /* skip index header */
for (i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
  uint32_t n = ntohl(index[i]);
  if (n < nr) {
    munmap(idx_map, idx_size);
    return error("non-monotonic index %s", path);
  }
  nr = n;
}
```

with [`ntohl` function being](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740069%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> The ntohl function converts a `u_long` from TCP/IP network order to host byte order (which is little-endian on Intel processors).
>
> The `ntohl` function returns the value supplied in the `netlong` parameter with the byte order reversed. If `netlong` is already in host byte order, then this function will reverse it. It is up to the application to determine if the byte order must be reversed.
>
> The `ntohl` function takes a 32-bit number in TCP/IP network byte order (the `AF_INET` or `AF_INET6` address family) and returns a 32-bit number in host byte order.

It is called by:

- [`open_pack_index()`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/sha1_file.c#L580), and
- [`parse_pack_index()`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/sha1_file.c#L973)

See the structure of a pack file in the SO question "[Is the git binary diff algorithm (delta storage) standardized?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9478023/is-the-git-binary-diff-algorithm-delta-storage-standardized/9478566#9478566)":

[image: pack file structure]

The first one is also called by [`builtin/fsck.c`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/builtin/fsck.c#L660-L675), so you can try a git fsck --full --progress, in order to check if you have a *local* corruption of your pack files, or if it actually is a remote repo issue.
Make sure you can replicate the issue on different OS and/or different version of Git.

The usual workaround, for a (here "Netduino") repo which seems to be forked around on GitHub, is to:

- clone another fork,
- restore one's own local modification from the corrupt repo, add them and commit them
- `push --force` back to one's own fork, in order to erase/reset the remote history by one with can be packed correctly

Comment: When you say clone another fork, is that the same as cloning the repo? I'm getting these above errors when I try to clone the repo.


And in step 2, to restore my local modifications would be to just "Reset File Changes" in Git Extensions?

Thanks

Comment: @Anshul Your repo has been copied (forked) multiple times on Github. Try to clone one of those other repos and see if the issue persists.

Comment: I'm not using GitHub, this is all on my personal computer. So if I understand you correctly, I should just take a copy of one of my other repositories and just use that? Essentially, delete my old broken repo and replace it with a new cloned one? Thanks

Comment: @Anshul yes, a local copy, or you can clone one of the GitHub repo as well (even if you don't use GitHub for storing new commits)

Comment: Yes, this was the solution I was eventually going to resort to as well. I tried it and it worked. I cloned one of my other personal repos and made that my central repo. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 9):

I was searching for info in this kind of non-monotonic error and found this link: http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/Error-non-monotonic-index-after-failed-recursive-quot-sed-quot-command-td7575014.html

TL;DR: you remove the non-monotonic index and then reindex it. In Linux it would be:

```
> rm .git/objects/pack/pack-29a18084cf61cd0322a6e9cfd485ce0977348c53.idx
> git index-pack .git/objects/pack/pack-29a18084cf61cd0322a6e9cfd485ce0977348c53.pack
```

After this I had to run some `git gc --prune=now` and `git remote prune origin`, but I had done some other operations before, so I may have spoiled my repo.

Answer (score 0):

Another reason: On MasOS, If you want ot git clone at a mobile disk, you must format it to APFS.

Comment: 1) This should be a comment under an answer, or an edit to an answer, not an answer itself.
2) Please take care to proofread your answers
3) Have an awesome day

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35018959)